# Google Drive transfer without a full upload

Tags: file-transfer, google-drive, data-transfer, imac

I currently have an iMac and I’m replacing it with another iMac

I think the first step I’m going to take is using migration assistant (from apple) to basically make both iMacs a duplicate

Can someone walk me through exactly what I need to do once this is done in order to avoid uploading gigabytes worth of data to google drive that I already have in my current iMac.

Basically google drive (on my current iMac) has the desktop folder synced

Answer (score 1):

You can migrate over ethernet or wifi directly from one to the other - it's one of the first questions the new Mac will ask you when you power up for the first time.

You need to have access to both Macs at the same time, because there is a security code needed as part of the routine, but it's all very easy to do.
The new Mac will end up being almost a clone of the old one [though differentiated so they don't get confused] & you can carry on as though nothing had changed.

You can do the same from a Time Machine backup - but Mac to Mac is very simple.

They don't even need to have been on the same OS, so old to new is just as easy as like to like.

Google Drive will know it's a new Mac so you'll have to sign in again, but it will be able to see what is already synced & not need to re-do it.

See [Apple KB - Move your content to a new Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT204350)

Comment: That’s the thing though, google drive will see it’s a new computer and want to create a whole new computer sync on the google drive server. I was reading other posts on how to trick it, I’m just not clear on that part

Comment: It's not something I can easily test, but I don't recall it ever being an issue.